# How to send library ebooks from Calibre to Nook

Tags: calibre, nook

Since I went from Vista to a new laptop and Windows 10, Adobe Digital Editions won't let me download books from my local library.  I have signed up with Calibre, but can't figure out how to transfer books from my local town library into the Calibre files to send to my Nook.  Anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: what ebook distribution system does your library use? What country are you in?

Answer (score 1):

First, I assume that you are referring to "protected ebooks" which when checked out requires some kind of Digital Rights Management. If they are not protected ebooks, I imagine you could just transfer them by USB -- and wouldn't need to answer the question.

Second, I am assuming that you live inside the USA.

Does your library use the Overdrive app? (That is probably the most common ebook distributor for libraries).

If yes, and if you use one of the color Nooks (like NOOK HD, NOOK HD+, etc), you can download an Overdrive app onto your Nook http://company.overdrive.com/overdrive-app-for-nook-makes-library-ebook-borrowing-even-easier/

It is much easier to check out ebooks via the Overdrive app than to transfer the encrypted epub file to your Nook via USB.

On a related note, I think it's worth upgrading to a Kindle Fire or an android tablet or even one of the Kindle e-ink devices -- especially if you use Overdrive. Even if your library uses another service beside Overdrive, chances are that they have a reading app which you can download to make it easier to check ebooks out directly. Nook is probably behind on connecting with libraries.

Did you know btw, that some libraries let you connect your Kindle e-ink device directly to your library, so if you check out the ebook, Overdrive (or another distributor) will send it directly to your e-ink device and then manage the checkin as well. Kindle is light years ahead of Nook.

Just recently Overdrive released a much more user friendly app called Libby which is much more useful than the previous Overdrive. It is available as an app in the Apple, Android and MS store. https://meet.libbyapp.com/